# Does Mathematica 12 scale with gnome display settings?

Tags: display, user-interface, scaling

I currently have Mathematica 11.3, and while I really like the software, windows are too tiny on my laptop. My laptop has a 4K monitor, and I have to manually increase the magnification every time I open a new document. Even then, this distorts the UI, and the menu up at the top of the notebook remains unchanged.

I'm currently running Gnome 3.34 on Ubuntu 19.10. Gnome scales most applications by 200%, but Mathematica 11.3 is unchanged independent of what settings I have for display scaling or font scaling.

Does Mathematica 12 correct this issue? I've been considering upgrading, and this would be a major usability improvement for me.

[image: This is what mathematica looks like on a 4K monitor.]

Comment: You might try `SetOptions[ $FrontEnd, Magnification -> 2 ]`  with either MMA 11.3 or 12.0.

Comment: Thank you! That increases the size of the Notebook, but it doesn't change the menu bar at the top